# ng-show is not working angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to hide and show the content within a specific div in my html for a popup.

home.html

```
 <div role="main" class="container theme-showcase">
      <div class="" style="margin-top:90px;">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2 id="tables">Search people</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
                <div class="alert alert-info" ng-hide=true>
                    <p>Sort key: {{sortKey}}</p>
                    <p>Reverse: {{reverse}}</p>
                    <p>Search String : {{search}}</p>
                </div>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Search</label>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th>
                                <span></span>
                          </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('firstName')">First Name
                            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='firstName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                           </th>
                           <th ng-click="sort('lastName')">Last Name
                               <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='lastName'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                           </th>
                               <th ng-click="sort('profession')">Job Title
                                  <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='profession'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                             </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-click="showModal($event, user.emailAddress)" dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">
                                    <td ><img src = {{user.profileImageUrl}} width="100" height="100"><img></td>
                                    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                                    <td>{{user.profession}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table> 

                    </div>
                <dir-pagination-controls
                    max-size="5"
                    direction-links="true"
                    boundary-links="true" >
                </dir-pagination-controls>
            </div>

            <!-- start -->

        <div class="panel-heading">

        <div ng-show="showAlert" >
          <div ng-include="'views/alert.html'"></div>
        </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

popup details , called from home.html

```
  <div ng-show="showAlert" >
          <div ng-include="'views/alert.html'"></div>
        </div>
```

alert.html

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="height: 3em;">
        <button type="button" ng-click="closeModal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<div ng-show="showDetails">
        <div><h3 class="text-danger">Job Title</h3></div> <!-- ithink you can change it-->
        <div><span class="genericText">{{alert.profession }}</span></div>
        <div class="genericText"><h3 class="text-danger">Approved Organisation</h3><div>
        <div><span class="genericText">{{alert.organisation}}</span></div>
          <div><h3 class="text-danger">Department</h3></div>
        <div><span class="genericText">{{alert.department}}</span></div>
      </div>     
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center; padding-top:2em" >
    <button type="button" ng-click="showRequestForm()" class="btn btn-default">Request Person</button>
  </div>
</div>


      <!-- FORM -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="requestForm" style="text-align:center" ng-submit="requestForm(requestForm.$valid)" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div id='genericText' style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : requestForm.email.$invalid && !requestForm.email.$pristine }">
            <input type="text" name="email" style="width:20em; height:3em; border-radius:0px" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="email" required>
            <!-- !loginForm.email.$pristine == false has not been used yet !-->
            <p ng-show="requestForm.email.$invalid && !requestForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email</p>
        </div>

        <br>
        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <button type="submit" id='submitButton' class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="requestForm.$invalid">Send Request</button>

    </form>


            <!-- end -->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Finally the code for in controller home.js

```
<div ng-show="showDetails">
```

home.js

```
     'use strict';

//app global variable
//this is the controller that handles post requests
//declare services as dependecies $http, $location, custom service apiServiceWeb
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, loggedInStatus, setCredentials, apiServiceWeb) {


  //get cookie, and then make api call
  var cookieData = setCredentials.getCookie('globals');

  console.log(cookieData);
  console.log("email " + cookieData.auth.username);
  console.log("userType " + cookieData.auth.userType);
  console.log("token " + cookieData.auth.token);

  var ctr_scope = $scope;
  $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array

  $scope.alert = {};
  $scope.showAlert = false;
  $scope.users = [{
    "busy": false,
    "emailAddress": "test@test",
    "userType": "test",
    "title": "test",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "dob": "tset",
    "profession": "test",
    "jobTitle": "test",
    "profileImageUrl": "test.jpg"
  }];

  $scope.sort = function(keyname) {
    $scope.sortKey = keyname; //set the sortKey to the param passed
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
  }

  /*$scope.test = function(text) {
    alert(text);

    //go to persons profile page
  }*/

  $scope.showModal = function(event, id) {


    //get object
    var user = $scope.users.filter(function(o) {
      return o.emailAddress == id
    })

    if (user[0]) {
      $scope.$parent.alert.profession = user[0].profession;
      $scope.$parent.alert.department = user[0].jobTitle;
      $scope.$parent.alert.organisation = 'test';

    }
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.$parent.showAlert = true;
    $scope.showDetails = false;

  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.showAlert = false;
  };


  $scope.showRequestForm = function(){

    //show request form

  };

});
```

I have tried

`$scope.$parent.showDetails = true;`

and

`$scope.showDetails = true;`

and yet it shows an empty pop up and can't detect between states.

Any idea why this is happening, thanks

Comment: Add full code of your `homeCtrl `, that will help to diagnose.

Comment: edited the code for you

Answer (score -1):

Your ng-show is most likely working fine. Especially as you state it just **shows** an empty div.
I think your issue here is that you are including a bootstrap modal which by default will be hidden.

Try removing the ng-show that wraps your ng-include for 'views/alert.html'

Use Javascript to trigger show modal:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Comment: You should not use JQuery in angular ... At the very least put this code in a directive and use angular.element instead of $('#mymodal')

Comment: Fair point about using Jquery in angular, my suggested solution was really just to confirm where his issue was coming from. Also note that angular.element is just an alias for the jQuery function.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the angular version of the bootstrap modal
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding why using JQuery in angularJS is a better idea than using the angular version of the component.

Comment: That is not the issue here, I think it that your answer doens't answer his problem/question but just refers to a different library.